# What's the passive form of "he did him dirty"?

Tags: idiomatic-language, slang

What's the passive form of "he did him dirty"?

He got done dirty? I think this is the correct form, but I am not 100% sure, because it sounds a bit odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"He got done dirty" is very informal and not, I think, passive voice.

"He was done dirty by him" is passive voice.

Answer (score 2):

It's such a thoroughly informal construction that I'm not sure it follows the usual grammatical rules enough that you *can* "convert" it into passive voice as such.

(I'm not even sure that "he did him dirty" is the usual idiom.  I've always heard it as "he did the dirty on him".  And no, you can't say "the dirty was done on him", that would be grammatically correct but idiomatically it would sound ridiculous.)

If you want a passive voice phrase that's similar, both in meaning and slang-ness, I'd go for "he was done down by him".